# How do you set the container for Autofac's MultitenantRequestService (version 5)

Tags: .net, autofac, multi-tenant

I just updated a working application's Autofac from version 4.8 to 6 which required me to update Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant from version 1 to 5.

My application is running on .NET core 2.1

Now the following .UseAutofacMultitenantRequestServices(() => Startup.ApplicationContainer) no longer works as this method is now parameterless and I can't figure out how to set it now.

```
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
    
            public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
            {
                return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseAutofacMultitenantRequestServices(() => Startup.ApplicationContainer)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddOptions();
                    });
            }
        }
```

When I remove that parameter I get this exception from CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

---

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Autofac.Multitenant.MultitenantContainer' while attempting to activate 'Autofac.Integration.AspNetCore.Multitenant.MultitenantRequestServicesMiddleware'.'

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#multitenant-support)? A lot has changed since the very first release.

Comment: Yes I have been reading those docs and all their examples with multiTenant assume you're on .NET core 3.0+

Comment: And you [dug in and looked at the actual running examples right in the multitenant repo](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/develop/samples/Sandbox.AspNetCore2_1_To_2_2/Program.cs)?